# Inject services into method in ASP.NET Core 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I'm looking for information on how to dynamically inject services into a class method using Dependency injection in ASP.Net Core.

For example, in ASP Middleware, you can inject any number of services into the the `Invoke` method, as opposed to the constructor. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#per-request-dependencies) explains how you can inject scoped services into your Middeware's `Invoke` method:

```
public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    // IMyScopedService is injected into Invoke
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IMyScopedService svc)
    {
        svc.MyProperty = 1000;
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

I would like to mimic the same behavior in my own code, but I cannot find any documentation explain how to achieve this. Currently I am creating a scope using `IServiceProvider.CreateScope` and passing the resulting `IServiceProvider` as a parameter to my function defined below:

```
public async Task DoWork(IServiceProvider services, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<RoomController>>();
            logger.LogInformation("Starting Room Controller.");
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

                logger.LogInformation("Room still running");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
```

I would like my function to look more like this:

```
public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken, ILogger<RoomController> logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Starting Room Controller.");
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

                logger.LogInformation("Room still running");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I was also curious so I went digging into github to see how it's done for middleware. Turns out it's largely a manual process:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/UseMiddlewareExtensions.cs

(Not copying the code here as it's quite a lot)

They inspect the method signature and compile a factory delegate which retrieves the required services from the `IServiceProvider` which lives in the `HttpContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) can help :

> - Registration of the dependency in a service container. ASP.NET Core provides a built-in service container, IServiceProvider. Services are registered in the app's Startup.ConfigureServices method.

You need to register in `ConfigureService` how you dependency injection should be resolved.

Comment: I am aware of how dependency injection works, but there is no documentation on that page describing how to achieve what I wrote in the original post.

Comment: Dies it help to add in ‘ConfugureService’ something like ‘services.AddTransient<ILogger<RoomController>, Logger<RoomController>>()’ and do ‘Invoke’ as you wish to do?